# How to query all properties of owl:Thing of dbpedia using SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology, dbpedia

When I use the following SPARQL query I get all properties of the DBpedia class Country:

```
select ?range ?domain ?prop ?label
Where{
    ?class rdfs:subClassOf{0,1} ?domain.
    ?prop rdfs:domain ?domain.
    ?prop rdfs:range ?range.
    ?prop rdfs:label ?label.
    FILTER(lang(?label) = 'en')
    FILTER(?class = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Country>)
}
```

When I try to do this with 'Thing' or 'OWL:Thing' or 'A Thing' or anything equivalent instead of Country, I get an empty result.

I want to adopt the ontology of DBpedia's owl:Thing, so I want to retrieve all properties of http://mappings.dbpedia.org/server/ontology/classes/owl%3AThing (including labela and range).

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is not property in DBpedia with the domain `owl:Thing`:

```sql
select * {
    ?prop rdfs:domain owl:Thing
}
```

The reason for this is probably that if no explicit domain is given, `owl:Thing` is the trivial domain. You can check this also if you look at particular properties from your referred list, e.g. [dbo:abbreviation](http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abbreviation)

Workaround query:

```sql
SELECT ?range (owl:Thing as ?domain) ?prop ?label {
 VALUES ?type {owl:DatatypeProperty owl:ObjectProperty}
 ?prop a ?type
 OPTIONAL {?prop rdfs:range ?range }
 ?prop rdfs:label ?label.
 FILTER(langmatches(lang(?label), 'en'))
 FILTER NOT EXISTS {?prop rdfs:domain ?domain}
}
```

Comment: (Directed at OP, not answerer:) Also, note that owl:Thing **is** a domain of every OWL property.  In OWL, "p rdfs:domain C" means that from a statement "p(x,y)" implies that "x rdf:type C".  When C is owl:Thing, that's "x rdf:type owl:Thing", which is *always* true.  That means that for *any* property p, "p(x,y) implies rdf:type(x,owl:Thing)" is true, so owl:Thing is *a* domain of every property.